# How to move ArrayList<Users> From child to Parent Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have a Child Activity which is returning an `ArrayList` to Parent Activity

**Child Activity**

```
ArrayList<Users> selectedMembers = new ArrayList<Users>();

//And then

Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

returnIntent.putExtra("ArrayOfUsers",selectedMembers);

setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);        

finish();
```

**Parent Activity**

Now how to get this `ArrayList<Users>` on parent Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            //how to get ArrayList<Users> here
        }
    }
```

I did something like this but i gives error

```
selectedMembers.addAll((data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("ArrayOfUsers"));
```

**error:**

`The method addAll(Collection<? extends Users>) in the type ArrayList<Users> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Parcelable>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different methods for serialization and deserialization. When you call `returnIntent.putExtra` actually [this](http://goo.gl/FCK1H) overloaded method in `Intent` class is called. So your list of users is actually treated as single `Serializable`object. In this case `putExtra` at child side should be used in conjunction with `getSerializableExtra` getter at parent side.

If you want to use `getParcelableArrayListExtra` at parent side as getter method you should use it in conjunction with `putParcelableArrayListExtra` at child side and you `Users` class should be `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `Users` class implementing the `Parcelable` interface? If not, this is why you are getting the message.

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayList` class implements `Serializable`, and that is how it is being taken for when you add your array list to the intent.

In order to retrieve the array list, you have to retrieve the serializable object and cast it back to `ArrayList` in the following manner:

```java
// Check that the result is successful and that the intent is valid (not null)
if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null ) {

    ArrayList<Users> selectedMembers = (ArrayList<Users>) data.getSerializableExtra ( "ArrayOfUsers" );

    // Your logic goes here ...
}
```

This casting process will trigger a warning in Eclipse IDE saying :
**Type safety: Unchecked cast from Serializable to ArrayList < Users >**

Do not worry about  this, you can just ignore the warning or simply add the following statement before your method :

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

---

**UPDATE :**

The object that you are storing in the array list must be serializable too, meaning that your class should implement serializable, which in your case, the class Users should in the following manner :

```
class Users implements Serializable {

    // ... 

}
```

Comment: Getting this error E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.services.entities.Users@43ef1590

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that your class Users should implement Serializable, please check the UPDATE section in my answer.